# Getting started with Git on Mac

Tags: git, ssh

I am new to Git (and to my Mac). I installed it on my Mac, but don't have a clue where to go from here. My professor emailed me a public/private ssh key pair - where/how do I insert these keys so that I can clone his code?

Comment: Did you try asking your professor about that?

Comment: Why is your professor giving you a private key? That defeats the entire purpose of private keys. You should generate your own with `ssh-keygen` and give your professor the public key.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need public/private key of your professor to be able to clone his repository.

What you need to do is to generate your own keypair with `ssh-keygen` and send the public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file) to your professor. He should set up the repository to allow authentication with this key.

On the side note: private key, as the name suggest, is private.  You don't want to share it with anyone. You also don't want to use a private/public key pair you got from someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by reading the Pro Git book, which is available for free online at [progit.org](http://progit.org).